# Does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments?

Tags: c#, class

I am currently doing some class coding and wonder what went wrong with my project?

```
class ContactPerson
{
    string name;
    ContactNo telNo;

    public ContactPerson(string in_Name, ContactNo in_No)
    {
        name = in_Name;
        telNo = new ContactNo();


    }
    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public ContactNo getContactInfo()
    {
        return telNo;
    }
    public void setName(string in_Name)
    {
        name = in_Name;
    }
    public void setContactInfo (ContactNo in_No)
    {
        telNo = in_No;
    }
}
```

}

```
class ContactNo
{
    string contactType;
    string contactNo;

    public void setContactType(string in_Type)
    {
        contactType = in_Type;
    }
    public string getContactType()
    {
        return contactType;
    }
    public void setContactNo(string in_No)
    {
        contactNo = in_No;
    }
    public string getContactNo()
    {
        return contactNo;
    }

}
```

}

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ContactNo telNo;
        telNo =   new ContactNo("Mobile No: ", 95656565);

        ContactPerson myFriend;
        myFriend = new ContactPerson("Fred Smith", telNo);
        string strName;
        strName = myFriend.getName();

        Console.WriteLine(" " + strName);
        ContactNo outContact;
        outContact = myFriend.getContactInfo();
        outContact.getContactType();
        Console.WriteLine(outContact);
        outContact.getContactNo();
        Console.WriteLine(outContact);

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

}

At the program class
" telNo =   new ContactNo("Mobile No: ", 95656565); "
theres error saying Does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments
may i know why?

Comment: coming from java, right? use [real Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) instead of `getABC()` and `setABC()` methods, please.

Comment: To elaborate at what @HighCore said, instead of getABC() and setABC, use things like public string YourString { get { return _yourString } set { _yourString = value } };

Comment: And then you can use property initializers: `telNo = new ContactNo() { ContactType = "Mobile No: ", Number = 95656565};`

Comment: @HighCore this made me so happy when I personally came over to C# from Java. :)

Comment: Also consider, strongly, leaving Hungarian notation where it belongs... in the past.

Comment: -1 for heaps of irrelevant code and 0 research effort... and apparently failing to even read the error

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner That's what separates men from children, I guess.

Answer (score 9):

That would be because you don't have a constructor that contains two arguments in the ContactNo class, as the error suggests. Take a look in the class, and you'll notice that there is no constructor there. You DO have one in the ContactPerson class, though.

This line: `telNo =   new ContactNo("Mobile No: ", 95656565);`
is calling a constructor for ContactNo that takes two arguments: a string, and an int. You don't have a constructor that is set up to do this currently, and that's where your error is. You could create one by adding

```
public ContactNo(string s, int n){
   //initializations
}
```

or something of that nature. Or, if you're using a string for the number (which it looks like), replace `int n` with `string s2` or whatever you wish to call it.

Answer (score 1):

because you dont have contact no constructor with 2 parameters. I guess you are confusing it with your other class that has 2 parameters

```
public ContactPerson(string in_Name, ContactNo in_No)
```

From your code it looks like you have to add this to your class **ContactNo**

```
 public ContactNo(string type, string umber)
{
    contactType = type;
    contactNo = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing a `string` and `int` I think you want to create a new `ContactPerson`, not `ContactNo`. However if you really want `ContactNo`, either add the constructor :

```
class ContactNo
{
    public string ContactType { get; set; }
    public string ContactNo { get; set; }

    public ContactNo(string type, string no)
    {
        ContactType = type;
        ContactNo = no;
    }
}
```

Or (with the properties) initialize it like this :

```
ContactNo contact = { ContactType = "The type", ContactNo = "The No" };
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ContactNo(string type, string umber)
{
        contactType = type;
        contactNo = number;
}
```

Add this in your ContactNo Class.

The reason you get error is because there is no constructor with two parameters.

Answer (score -1):

add the following to your ContactNo class:

```
public ContactNo(string inType, string inNo)
{
   contactType = inType;
   contactNo = inNo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have constructor to take 2 parameters. Add this constructor in your ContactNo class

```
public ContactNo(string contactType, string contactNo)
{
    this.contactType = contactType;
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the constructor for your `ContactNo` class. Classes only provides a default constructor with no arguments.

The constructor you need is the following:

```
public ContactNo(string contactType, string contactNo) {
    this.contactType = contactType;
    this.contactNo = contactNo;
}
```